# Nav bar get Active for two items

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc

in my web project, I used a free theme https://themewagon.com/themes/free-bootstrap-4-html-5-admin-dashboard-website-template-skydash/

Here in the `nav` bar, I customized it as

```
<nav class="sidebar sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link elements" href="~/Home/Index">
        <i class="icon-grid menu-icon"></i>
        <span class="menu-title">Dashboard</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="@Url.Action("Index","SelfService")">
        <i class="ti-menu-alt menu-icon"></i>
        <span class="menu-title">Our Services</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="@Url.Action("OnProcessTasks","SelfCareTasks")">
        <i class="ti-timer menu-icon"></i>
        <span class="menu-title">In Process Tasks</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="@Url.Action("CompletedTasks","SelfCareTasks")">
        <i class="ti-file menu-icon"></i>
        <span class="menu-title">Completed Tasks</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="@Url.Action("OnProcessTasks","SelfCareTasks")">
        <i class="ti-face-smile menu-icon"></i>
        <span class="menu-title">My Profile</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

My issue is When I run this, on load first 2 items showed as `Active` and both items are highlighted. I checked with the sample, but it runs without this issue, also I tried removing the `href` and then the nav bar showed only one item as active.

[image]

I still couldn't figure out why this happening. Any comments?

Comment: Please add a code example on codepen/codesandbox etc which replicates the issue.

Comment: @TashrikAnam hi, I think uploading the issue to the codepen will be difficult. there are few js and css files related to this.

Comment: Try to share your css and js in Network,maybe you missed something.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see what is wrong other than just this thing:

```
            <a class="nav-link elements" href="~/Home/Index">
```

Change it to:

```
      <a class="nav-link elements" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">
```

The reason for this change is because you're following the Razor Syntax.